# Values are passing NULL when I record in the base in ASP MVC , SQL and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am developing an ASP .Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I am using also Entity Framework and Code First Method.

My problem is that the values are passing NULL when I want to record in the base.

[image]

and The error is :

> Can not insert the value NULL into column 'ID_Gamme' table
>   'Flux.dbo.Gamme'. This column does not accept NULL values. INSERT
>   failed. The statement has been terminated

To explain ,,I have 3 tables :
**Profile_Ga**(ID_Gamme(PK),.....)
**Poste**(ID_Poste(PK),....)
**Gamme**(ID_Poste(PK),ID_Gamme(PK),....) which is a relation table between Poste and Profile_Ga.

And I want to record in the table **Gamme** using parametres from the other 2 tables.

So This is the Form where I will enter the parametres :
[image: form]

So let's began with the Views, this is the code of Index :

```
    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Anouar"))
   { %>
  <div><%:Html.Label("Gamme :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedProfile_Ga", new SelectList(Model.Profile_GaItems, "ID_Gamme", "ID_Gamme"))%> <input type="button" value="Configurer" id="btnShowGestion" /></div> 




<div id="divGestion"><%: Html.Partial("Gestion", Model) %></div>
       <% } %>   
and this is the Partial View 'Gestion.ascx' :

    <fieldset class="parametrage">
            <legend>Gestion de Gamme</legend>

            <div><%:Html.Label("Poste :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedPoste", Model.PostesItems)%><input type="checkbox" name="option1" value="Poste Initial" id= "chkMain" onclick="test();"/>Poste Initial<input type="checkbox" name="option2" value="Poste Final" id= "chkFirst" onclick="test2();"/>Poste Final</div>


             <div><%:Html.Label("Nombre de Passage :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(x=>x.YourGammeModel.Nbr_Passage)%></div>
            <div><%:Html.Label("Position :")%><%: Html.EditorFor(x=>x.YourGammeModel.Position)%></div>
            <div><%:Html.Label("Poste Précédent :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("PostePrecedentSelected", Model.PostesItems)%></div>
            <div><%:Html.Label("Poste Suivant :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("PosteSuivantSelected", Model.PostesItems)%></div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" id="btnSave"  /></div>

            </fieldset>
```

and this is the Controller that populate the view 'Index' :

```
public class ProfileGaController : Controller
    {
        private GammeContext db = new GammeContext();

        //
        // GET: /ProfileGa/
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(Profile_Ga profile_ga, Poste poste)
        {

            var viewModel = new FlowViewModel();
            viewModel.PostesItems = new SelectList(db.Postes.ToList(), "ID_Poste", "ID_Poste"); 
            //viewModel.PostesItems = db.Postes.ToList() ?? new List<Poste>();
               viewModel.Profile_GaItems = db.Profil_Gas.ToList();
               viewModel.GaItems = db.Gammes.ToList();

            return View(viewModel);



        }
```

and this is the Controller which populate the PartialView :

```
public class AnouarController : Controller
    {

         private GammeContext db = new GammeContext();


        //
        // GET: /Anouar/

         public ActionResult Gestion(FlowViewModel model)
         {

             model.YourGammeModel = new Gamme();
             return PartialView(model);

         }

         [HttpPost]
         public ActionResult Create(FlowViewModel model)
         {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                db.Gammes.Add(model.YourGammeModel);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Gestion");  
            }


            return View(model.YourGammeModel);
        }
    }
```

Note : This Controller is one which contain the function 'Create' that allow us to record in the base.

And Finally this is The ViewModel that contains the attributs :

```
public class FlowViewModel
    {

        [Key]
        public string IDv { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public SelectList PostesItems { get; set; }

        public List<Profile_Ga> Profile_GaItems { get; set; }
        public List<Gamme> GaItems { get; set; }

        public Gamme YourGammeModel { get; set; }

        public int SelectedProfile_Ga { get; set; }

        public int SelectedGamme{ get; set; }

        public int SelectedPoste { get; set; }

        public int PostePrecedentSelected { get; set; } 
        public int PosteSuivantSelected { get; set; }        
    }
```

I think that 'YourGammeModel' doesn't have all its properties set though. That is problem.

The code of GammeContext :

```
public class GammeContext : DbContext
    {
        public GammeContext()
        {

            Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<GammeContext>());

        }


        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ns_AFaire> Ns_AFaires { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Famille> Familles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Fonction> Fonctions { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Fonction_Poste> Fonction_Postes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Gamme> Gammes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Historique> Historiques { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Ligne> Lignes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Phase> Phases { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Poste> Postes { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Produit> Produits { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Profile_Ga> Profil_Gas { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Sous_Famille> Sous_Familles { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UF> UFs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Num_Serie> Num_Series { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions.PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

        public DbSet<FlowViewModel> FlowViewModels { get; set; }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include all the fields from your model when returning it back to the controller

Use `<%: Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.YourGammeModel.[[Field]]%>` for each of the fields

Comment: thx,,,but this error appear :
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

System.Data.Edm.EdmAssociationConstraint: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical.

Comment: Oooooh wait, are you doing an HttpPost?

Comment: yes Http Post,,,and please check my update to see the code of Gamme Context

Comment: ok and I let the edit of the FlowViewModel which you post it first?

Comment: Try it without to start with

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30128/discussion-between-anouar-and-matt)